# Concatenating matrices within for-loop in MatLab

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix, populate

In MatLab, I have a matrix SimC which has dimension 22 x 4. I re-generate this matrix 10 times using a `for` loop.

I want to end up with a matrix `U` that contains `SimC(1)` in rows 1 to 22, `SimC(2)` in rows 23 to 45 and so on. Hence U should have dimension 220 x 4 in the end.

Thank you!!

Edit:

```
nTrials = 10;
n = 22;
U = zeros(nTrials * n , 4)      %Dimension of the final output matrix

for i = 1 : nTrials

   SimC = SomeSimulation()    %This generates an nx4 matrix 
   U = vertcat(SimC)   

end
```

Unfortunately the above doesn't work as  `U = vertcat(SimC)` only gives back `SimC` instead of concatenating.

Comment: Take a look at vertcat maybe?

Comment: thanks, vertcat looks promising. However I can't get it to work within the code:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertcat` is a good choice, but it will result in a growing matrix.  This is not good practice on larger programs because it can really slow down.  In your problem, though, you aren't looping through too many times, so `vertcat` is fine.

To use `vertcat`, you would NOT pre-allocate the full final size of the `U` matrix...just create an empty `U`.  Then, when invoking `vertcat`, you need to give it both matrices that you want to concatenate:

```
nTrials = 10;
n = 22;
U = []      %create an empty output matrix
for i = 1 : nTrials
    SimC = SomeSimulation();    %This generates an nx4 matrix
    U = vertcat(U,SimC);  %concatenate the two matrices 
end
```

The better way to do this, since you already know the final size, is to pre-allocate your full `U` (as you did) and then put your values into `U` via computing the correct indices.  Something like this:

```
nTrials = 10;
n = 22;
U = U = zeros(nTrials * n , 4);      %create a full output matrix
for i = 1 : nTrials
    SimC = SomeSimulation();    %This generates an nx4 matrix
    indices = (i-1)*n+[1:n];  %here are the rows where you want to put the latest output
    U(indices,:)=SimC;  %copies SimC into the correct rows of U 
end
```